# Какой метод жизненного цикла фрагмента срабатывает при добавлении в backStack?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой метод жизненного цикла фрагмента срабатывает при добавлении в backStack? Мне необходимо при добавлении фрагмента в backStack снимать с регистрации EventBus, а при возобновлении отображения фрагмента заново его регистрировать. Какой метод мне может в этом помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагменты, как и активности, могут управляться кнопкой Back. Вы можете добавить несколько фрагментов, а потом через кнопку Back вернуться к первому фрагменту. Если в стеке не останется ни одного фрагмента, то следующее нажатие кнопки закроет активность.

Чтобы добавить транзакцию в стек, вызовите метод `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(String)` перед завершением транзакции (`commit`). Строковый аргумент - опциональное имя для идентификации стека или `null`. Класс `FragmentManager` имеет метод `popBackStack()`, возвращающий предыдущее состояние стека по этому имени.

Если вы вызовете метод `addToBackStack()` при удалении или замещении фрагмента, то будут вызваны методы фрагмента `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroyView()`.

Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку возврата, то вызываются методы фрагмента `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, `onStart()` и `onResume()`.

[Взял отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!!!!